# How do I create a dictionary from two lists, one of them being nested?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-lists

I have two lists of data, one of them containing labels:

```
labels = ['timestamp', 'hour', 'day']
```

Another list is nested value list, looking like this:

```
 values = [[1543449657, 13, 'Monday'], [1543449690, 0, 'Thursday'], [1543449841, 15, 'Sunday']]
```

I want to create a dictionary which takes a key from the the *labels* list and loops through *values* in the second list, so the output would look like:

```
{
    "timestamp": [1543449657, 1543449690, 1543449841],
    "hour": [13, 0, 15],
    "day": ['Monday', 'Thursday', 'Sunday']
}
```

I am posting my code below.

```
dic = {} 
for key in labels: 
    for sublist in values:
        for value in sublist:
            dic[key] = value
            sublist.remove(value)
            break
print(dic)
```

It only inserts values from the first row.

```
{'timestamp': 1543449657, 'hour': 13, 'day': 'Monday'}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your problem is you are not creating a list of values for each keys of your dictionnary, you are just rewriting the value of dic[key] everytime dic[key] = value is called.

Comment: @r.ook I'm referring to all their previous questions, not this one

Comment: @EdChum-ReinstateMonica Oh wow wouldn't have guessed it.  That's not a good look on the history.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dict comprehension here

```
>>> {key: [sub[index] for sub in values] for index, key in enumerate(labels)}
{'timestamp': [1543449657, 1543449690, 1543449841],
 'hour': [13, 0, 15],
 'day': ['Monday', 'Thursday', 'Sunday']}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can zip the sublists of `values` together to get the values of your dictionary:

```
dict(zip(labels, zip(*values)))
# {'timestamp': (1543449657, 1543449690, 1543449841), 'hour': (13, 0, 15), 'day': ('Monday', 'Thursday', 'Sunday')}
```

If you need them to be lists, you can map `list` over them

```
dict(zip(labels, map(list, zip(*values))))
# {'timestamp': [1543449657, 1543449690, 1543449841], 'hour': [13, 0, 15], 'day': ['Monday', 'Thursday', 'Sunday']}
```